# How to paste image in Richtext area in IE

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

How can i paste an image into a Richtext area/in any component in IE.

I have tried through "clipboard data", it is working fine in Google chrome.

However is not working in IE.

**Could anybody suggest solution for the same ?**

Comment: It will depend entirely on the 'richtext area' plugin you are using. Can you tell us which it is.

Comment: It is a iFrame. Is it possible to paste image in a iFrame/div or any component in IE?